# Обратная связь в Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Проблемка следующего характера: при попытке отправить сообщение через контроллер (класс `'email'`) данные, в который прилетают из формы (выводится из базы данных, если это важно), происходит редирект на главную страницу и УСЁ).

Код формы:

```
<form method="post" action="obratka" id="feedback-form">
Как к Вам обращаться:
<input type="text" name="nameFF" required placeholder="фамилия имя отчество" x-autocompletetype="name">
Email для связи:
<input type="email" name="contactFF" required placeholder="адрес электронной почты" x-autocompletetype="email">
Ваше сообщение:
<textarea name="messageFF" required rows="5" placeholder="Здравствуйте,"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="obratka" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Далее код контроллера:

```
function obratka()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $data['pages'] = $this->pages_model->get_pages();
        $data['pages_dop'] = $this->pages_model->get_pages_dop();
        $data['pages_dop2'] = $this->pages_model->get_pages_dop2();
        $data['pages_info'] = $this->pages_model->get_pages_info($title);
        $data['categories'] = $this->pages_model->get_cat();
        $data['latest_articles'] = $this->pages_model->get_latest_articles();
        $data['user'] = $this->session->userdata('user');
        $data['user_info']['status'] = $this->session->userdata('status');
        $data['user_info']['avatar'] = $this->session->userdata('avatar');
        $data['error'] = '';
        if($this->input->post('obratka'))
        {
            $this->load->model('rules_model');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->rules_model->obratka);
            $check = $this->form_validation->run();
            if($check == TRUE)
            {
                $name2 = $this->input->post('nameFF');
                $email2 = $this->input->post('contactFF');             
                $text2 = $this->input->post('messageFF');

                $this->load->library('email');

                $this->email->from($email2, $name2);
                $this->email->to('моё_мыло@mail.ru');           
                $this->email->subject('Тестовое сообщение');
                $this->email->message($text2);

                $this->email->send();

                $data['error'] = "Ваш вопрос успешно оптравлен владельцу сайта. Спасибо за проявленный интерес. Я отвечу Вам в течении одного рабочего дня!";
                $name = 'info';
                $this->template->page_view($data,$name);
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            $data['error'] = "вы все ....";
            $name = 'obr';
            $this->template->page_view($data,$name);
        }
    }
```

Добрые люди, подскажите, что может быть неверно написано? Уже голову сломал... 2 дня бьюсь. ))
P.S. Сильно не серчайте - начинающий программист. ) Есть догадки, что всё из-за того, что сама форма выводится из базы данных...

**Обновление**

Плиз, хэлп... не могу найти ошибку. Вот лог:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2014:21:07:52 +0400] "POST /index.php/pages/obratka HTTP/1.1" 302 -   
> 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2014:21:07:53 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 19936

Вроде данные приходят через POST. Что не так, не пойму.

**Обновление 2**

Поправил

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail
From: "llllllll" <llll@mail.ru>
Return-Path: <llll@mail.ru>
Reply-To: "llll@mail.ru" <llll@mail.ru>
X-Sender: llll@mail.ru
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <545a735840d40@mail.ru>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?=d0=a2=d0=b5=d1=81=d1=82=d0=be=d0=b2=d0=be=d0=b5_=d1=81=d0=be?=
 =?utf-8?Q?=d0=be=d0=b1=d1=89=d0=b5=d0=bd=d0=b8=d0=b5?=
llllllllll
```

Ведь я указал адрес получателя `-$this->email->to('моё_мыло@mail.ru');`
Что неверно?

Comment: Вас смущает то, что идет редирект на главную страницу после успешной отправки и валидации формы? Так это нормально - иначе обновлением страницы вы будете получать постоянно данные из формы.

Comment: Поставь в action адрес страницы, где используется контроллер с функцией obratka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В action должен быть URL на функцию обработчик, а не просто название функции.

**Обновление**

Попробуйте после проверки на post поставить `var_dump($_POST); exit;`, чтобы посмотреть, заходит ли вообще в условие скрипт. А еще лучше если есть, то смотрите через xdebug.

Comment: Может, я чего не понимаю, но принцип ведь работы такой: из формы в функцию obratka попадают данные и сохраняются в переменные $email2, $name2, $text2, после отправляются через класс 'email' мне на почту?

Comment: Ещё одно небольшое дополнение: всё это крутится на denwer. Может быть, в нём причина?

Comment: поправил
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail
From: "llllllll" <llll@mail.ru>
Return-Path: <llll@mail.ru>
Reply-To: "llll@mail.ru" <llll@mail.ru>
X-Sender: llll@mail.ru
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <545a735840d40@mail.ru>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?=d0=a2=d0=b5=d1=81=d1=82=d0=be=d0=b2=d0=be=d0=b5_=d1=81=d0=be?=
 =?utf-8?Q?=d0=be=d0=b1=d1=89=d0=b5=d0=bd=d0=b8=d0=b5?=
llllllllll
ведь я указал адрес получателя-$this->email->to('моё_мыло@mail.ru');
Что неверно

Comment: Спасибо, @Barton. )

Comment: Я могу выложить готовый скрипт?или это уже будет лишним?вопрос к админам)

Comment: @semjaza ну, если спасибо, то принимайте ответ. ) Не за что.

Answer (score 1):

Первый раз вижу что-то подобное, если честно. :)

```
if($this->input->post('obratka'))
```

С этим-то всё ясно, там есть сабмит с таким именем, но вот

```
action="obratka"
```

я не могу понять вообще.

Comment: В том то всё и дело, что отправки не происходит. ) Экшен записан так, потому что выводится из базы данных (сама форма)...)) Может нужно как-то по-другому? )

Comment: По идее, должно быть так: `<?=base_url();>index.php/pages/obratka`.  

Но так тоже не работает. )